# Assign new value to the fetched data from query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, strftime

I'm trying to format the date which is received from the query in rails but the value is not updated.
Here is my code :-

```
@data = "My query"
@data.each do |eventdata|
      eventdata.start_date = eventdata.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
      puts "*******************"+eventdata.start_date.to_s
      eventdata.end_date = eventdata.end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
end
```

The date received from my ajax call is in this format `'2012-12-06T00:00:00+05:30'`,it is not updated. What could be the issue?

Also the event value printed on my console is  `******************2012-12-06 00:00:00 +0530`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 eventdata.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%p")
```

or

```
 eventdata.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Try using Date.parse method.
Date.parse(eventdata.start_date.to_s).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")